# Group by ID and count comma split text in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a dataframe like this,

```
customer    tags
0   A   chocolate, sprinkles
1   A   chocolate, filled
2   B   chocolate, filled
3   C   chocolate, sprinkles
4   C   glazed
5   B   chocolate, filled
6   A   chocolate, sprinkles
7   C   glazed
```

How do I split the text tags then count for each customer?

My expected output is,

```
customer    chocolate   sprinkles   filled  glazed
   A            3           2         1       0
   B            2           0         2       0
   C            1           1         0       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split`, `explode` and `crosstab`:

```
df = df.assign(tags=df["tags"].str.split(", ")).explode("tags")

print (pd.crosstab(df["customer"],df["tags"]))

tags      chocolate  filled  glazed  sprinkles
customer                                      
A                 3       1       0          2
B                 2       2       0          0
C                 1       0       2          1
```